# Why is a variable in a `require`d module not always available?

Tags: puppet

I've got three module manifests in separate files (stripped down to bare essentials):

```
class users {
  $user = 'foo'

  user { $user:
    ensure => present;
  }
}

class dvcs_cli {
  require users

  file { "/home/${::users::user}/.gitconfig":
    ensure => present,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/dvcs_cli/.gitconfig';
  }
}

class shell {
  require users

  file { "/home/${::users::user}/.bash_aliases":
    ensure => present,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/shell/bash_aliases.sh';
  }
}
```

`.gitconfig` is created in `/home/foo` as expected, but **`.bash_aliases` is created in `/home`**:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/puppet apply --modulepath modules --detailed-exitcodes --hiera_config=hieradata/hiera.yaml manifests/host.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]
[…]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Shell/File[/home//.bash_aliases]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}[…]'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Shell/File[/home/foo/.gitconfig]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}[…]'
```

It's as if `${::users::user}` evaluates to the empty string in one module, but not in the other. How is this possible?

---

Running with `--debug` revealed a possible issue: **`User[foo]` is autorequired for `dvcs_cli`, but not for `shell`:**

```
$ grep 'Adding autorequire relationship with User' puppet.log | grep -i -e dvcs_cli -e shell
Debug: /Stage[main]/Dvcs_cli/File[/home/pair/.gitconfig]: Adding autorequire relationship with User[pair]
```

This contradicts the [manual](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.2/reference/type.html#file), which says:

> If Puppet is managing the user or group that owns a file, the file resource will autorequire them.

Could this be related to the ["Autorequire relationships are opaque"](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/latest/known_issues.html#autorequire-relationships-are-opaque), caused by the fact that both files are in the same directory? And shouldn't autorequires be irrelevant anyway, since both modules explicitly `require users`?

---

Running

```
$ puppet --version
4.2.1
```

on

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in an odd situation, and for me it was Puppet silently breaking a cycle, but not in a predictable way (nor in `--debug` output).  I saw this behavior once before but it 'went away' after some other changes so I never really understood.

Scenario:

```
class a {
  include b

  $foo = 'quick'
  $bar = $b::baz
}

class b {
  include a

  $baz = 'brown'

  if ($hostname == $baz) {
    $qux = $a::foo
  }
}
```

here `$bar` was `undef` after changing class `c` that included both `a` and `b` conditionally - yet both `a` and `b` were untouched.  This appears to be incorrect behavior.

The workaround was:

```
class b {
  $baz = 'brown'

  if ($hostname == $baz) {
    include a
    $qux = $a::foo
  }

}
```

And then `$bar` was defined again.  There's a way to visualize cycles with dot files but I haven't gone that deep into it.

Puppet 5.5.22 (Debian stable)